# consoleでnet::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)のエラーが発生してしまい、それが解消できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

私は、consoleでfont_1_honokamin.ttfのエラーが発生しているが、解消することができない状態にいます。

```html
style.scss

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ほのか明朝';
    src: url('font_1_honokamin.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

View 

<link href=" https://change_change.com/assets/font_1_honokamin.ttf" rel="font">
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/172330

Answer (score 1):

[ほのか明朝](http://font.gloomy.jp/honoka-mincho-dl.html) フォントがサーバー上に無いので 404 (Not found) というエラーになっています。console に出力されたURLで このフォントが参照できるようにサーバー上に配置してください。

Comment: サーバー上というのは、ここでいうとどこにあたるのでしょうか？

Comment: `https://chancetochance.world/assets/font_1_honokamin.ttf` というURLでアクセスした時に接続されるサーバーです。このURLでファイルが見える場所に .ttf ファイルを保存してみてください。